# compute mean of groups of variables

Tags: loops, repeat, spss

I have 360 variables: trail1 to trail360 and want to compute new variables that is is the mean of each 18 blocks: mean1 of trail1 to trail20, mean2 of trail 21 to 40 and so forth

I can do:

```
COMPUTE mean1=MEAN(trial1 TO trail20).
COMPUTE mean2=MEAN(trial21 TO Trail40).
...
COMPUTE mean18=MEAN(trail341 TO Trail360).
```

but is there a way to repeat or loop the command for the blocks containing 20 subsequent variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! couldn't find a very easy way to fully automate this, but here is what I came up with:

```
dataset name orig./* this is for your original data, so we can get back to it later.

* first we create parameters for our later calculations.
input program.
loop mn=1 to 18.
end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
compute nd = 20*mn.
compute bg = nd-19.

* the parameters are now ready, we'll use them to write the commands we need.
string cmd (a50).
compute cmd = concat("compute trailmean", ltrim(string(mn,f3)), " = mean(trail",
              ltrim(string(bg,f3)), " to trail", ltrim(string(nd,f3)), ").").

* now we write these commands to a new syntax file.
write out="c:\yourpath\calc means.sps" /cmd.
exe.

* and then run the new syntax on the original data.
dataset activate orig.
insert file="c:\yourpath\calc means.sps".
exe.
```